# spark kafka integration checkpoint reuse

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I use approach 2 from http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html , I use check pointing, and when I had to change code, and redeploy my code , sometimes checkpointing is throwing exceptions, and if for some reason, I had to delete the checkpoint directory , how can I reuse the checkpoint directory folders to get messages from kafka , I think the checkpoint directory has kafka offsets stored.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/exactly-once-spark-streaming-from-apache-kafka/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen that. Re-compiled code does throw exception sometimes(very weird ones) while using checkpointing.

In all fairness, the point of checkpointing is that if there is a data related problem, you should be able to recover from it.

Yes: When you do checkpointing for KafkaDstream your offsets get stored.
So when you recover, you start from where you left last.

If you want more fine grained control of your Kafka offsets, take a look at [cody's example](https://github.com/manasdebashiskar/kafka-exactly-once/tree/master/src/main/scala/example). He is the guy who wrote Direct KafkaDstream.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I reuse the checkpoint directory folders to get messages from
>   kafka , I think the checkpoint directory has kafka offsets stored

If you changed your code, you can't. Spark Streaming checkpointing doesn't only persist the underlying RDD, it also persists metadata, such as the spark graph ran at the point in time, so it can reconstruct the lineage when resuming after a crash, for example.

This means that if you do change your code, you'll have to delete any checkpointed data before resuming your streaming job. This will also mean the kafka offsets stored in your checkpoint directory will be of no use to you. This is why it's recommended to manually persist your offsets if you're using the receiverless stream approach introduced in Spark 1.3.

[From the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html) (emphasis mine):

> Note that one disadvantage of this approach is that it does not update
>   offsets in Zookeeper, hence Zookeeper-based Kafka monitoring tools
>   will not show progress. **However, you can access the offsets processed
>   by this approach in each batch and update Zookeeper yourself (see
>   below)**.

There's even a snippet of code to get you started:

```
 // Hold a reference to the current offset ranges, so it can be used downstream
var offsetRanges = Array[OffsetRange]()

directKafkaStream.transform { rdd =>
  offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
  rdd
}.map { // Do stuff
}.foreachRDD { rdd =>
   for (o <- offsetRanges) {
     println(s"${o.topic} ${o.partition} ${o.fromOffset} ${o.untilOffset}")
   }
}
```